# Asp.net Ajax , Hangs Sometimes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I use ASP.net Ajax on my project. and using Session for state management.

in some piece of code , I have some modalpop up , that contain UCs and do some things.

If I use UpdatePanel , sometimes, when I open popup, for a long time progress bar shows and dont do any things. if I refresh page it will work correctly.
Also If I remove the UpdatePanel all methods work perfectly.

on pages that I have more than one popup( or any method that I run under update panel) I have this problem.

What was wrong? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is get [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and look for any outstanding requests.

Answer (score 0):

What type of browser are you using? Sometimes Google Chrome suffer from this problem like my personal website. Unfortunately, I've no idea what's going on,too.

Comment: I use IE 7 , 8 and firefox and the result was same

Answer (score 0):

Check with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), in console mode you can see what http requests are sent, and if they already got a response (and see its response). It's a good place to start debugging everything that has to do with Ajax.

Comment: Many thanks for your (and AnthonyWJones) Suggestion. I check this but I'm not familiar with Firebug and can’t use it till now.
I can’t use it for localhost , it shows all request for external Url not local , and I can’t check it in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that leaving IPv6 enabled when you don't actually have a network which supports it can sometimes introduce lag like this, while the system tries IPv6 (and eventually times out, then reverting to IPv4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I didnt enable IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 is enabled by default on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

for more information , I load UC dynamiclly on page in OnInit method, therefore on every post back , UC load again , before when I load UC static , I have not this problem such as now.
Also I use ModalUpdateProgress , that was a third party and open source control for Progressbar